# Fetch rows from the last hour (prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In my MySQLi database, I have a table which contains the field "timestamp". Here, I store the Unix timestamp when a row is added (PHP `time()`).

Now I want to fetch all rows that were added the last hour:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('timestamp')) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```

But this seems to fetch ALL the rows, not those of the last hour.

What am I doing wrong? This has been asked before, but I tried those solutions but can't seem to find a working example for my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, i hope work.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME('timestamp') > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```

Or

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```